# XMessageControl UIMessage not working on monodroid

Tags: notifications, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, renderer

I am trying to change the way notifications are shown on my Xamarin.forms project and when adding the [Softweb.Controls.UIMessage](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xmessagecontrol) component it won't show either the message or toast.

```
UIMessage.ShowMessage ("Customization", "Hey! You Clicked on Button", MessageControl.MessageTypes.Warning, "red.png", Color.BrandRed, Color.Black, true, OnDissmissControl);
```

I running this code from a dependency controller, I was wondering if the error is caused by not having the right context, but I see not way to add one to the class. Has anyone try using this component on a Xamarin.forms project? (this is specific to MonoDroid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, just make sure you are running on the mainthread and it should work. This would have been much easier if the library had some documentation worth looking at.

```
    [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (.Android.MessageBar))]
namespace .Android
{
    public class MessageBar : IMessageBar
    {
        public MessageBar ()
        {
        }

        public void Show(MessageType messageType, string title, string message)
        {
            var context = Forms.Context;

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                //CustomToast customtoast=new CustomToast(context, messageType, title, message);
                UIMessage.ShowMessage ("Customization", "Hey! You Clicked on Button", MessageControl.MessageTypes.Warning, "validation.png", Color.BrandRed, Color.Black, true, OnDissmissControl);

            });


        }
        public void OnDissmissControl()
        {

        }
    }
}
```